# How to set basepath for openapi with servicestack?

Tags: c#, servicestack, servicestack-openapi

The REST endpoints of my application all start with /api/. The swagger-ui lists all  REST pathes under /api/, which is a mess. I want to set the basepath to /api/, so that only the REST endpoints are shown.

According to https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/api-host-and-base-path/ it should be simple, but using the ServiceStack OpenApiFeature from ServiceStack.API.OpenApi 5.7.0 I can't see where to access that property.

Does anyone know how to set the basepath property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the Open API v2 model using the [OpenApiFeature plugins Operation Filters](https://docs.servicestack.net/openapi#operation-filters), e.g. you can change the BasePath property with:

```
Plugins.Add(new OpenApiFeature {
    ApiDeclarationFilter = x => x.BasePath = ...
});
```

Although I don't expect modifying auto generated properties like `BasePath` is going to have your desired behavior. ServiceStack's [Open API feature](https://docs.servicestack.net/openapi) only lists ServiceStack Services, not MVC routes.

Comment: Your are right, the MVC routes are not contained, I edited my question. You are also right, that the method you described didn't help to list the routes the way I wanted. Using ServiceStack TagAttribute did the trick!